# How to export captured data from PDF into a DataFrame? [RegEx]

Tags: python, excel, regex, pandas, csv

```
import re
import pdfplumber 
import pandas as pd
from collections import namedtuple
path = r"C:\Users\x\Documents\Python Scripts\Files\x.pdf"
Line = namedtuple('Line', 'print_date order_no pos item_no issue qty UM price req_date line_amt')

with pdfp.open(path) as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[2]
    text = page.extract_text()

new_vend_re = re.compile(r'^\d{1,}\s[A-Z].*')
for line in text.split('\n'):
    if new_vend_re.match(line):
        print(line)
```

This finds and prints something like this:

```
53 AB839-11 0002 31.00 EA 58.5300 1814.43
```

There are pages and pages that have to extract similar values like those. That's just an example.
Remaining code that does the processing:

```
line_items = []

with pdfplumber.open(path) as pdf:
    pages = pdf.pages
    for page in pdf.pages:
        text = page.extract_text()
        for line in text.split('\n'):
            line = new_vend_re.search(line)
            if line:
                pos = line.group(1)
                item_no = line.group(2)
                issue = line.group(3)
                qty = line.group(4)
                UM = line.group(5)
                price = line.group(6)
                amt = line.group(7)
                line_items.append(Inv(pos, item_no, issue, qty, UM, price, amt))

df = pd.DataFrame(line_items)
df.head()
```

I've got this code but it doesn't seem to be able to put the extracted data into their respective tuples.
My program should basically iterate through the PDF which has multiple pages and exact the values I get from the various extracted items from the regex expression and put them in the tuple but my code doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Remove all the pdf handling stuff - it is irrelevant, we do not have your pdf and can not exectute your code on your file to get the text your regex operate on. Hardcode / add example text you extract from pdf and want to apply your regexes to.  [edit] - [ask].

Comment: I just wish to extract the data I've taken from the regex mentioned below it,

(53 AB839-11 0002 31.00 EA 58.5300 1814.43)

I want these to be separated individually and be put to DataFrame/csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is wrong - it starts with `"^\d+"` - meaning start of line followed by digits.
The line in your file starts with `"(......)"` - change the regex:

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple

Inv = namedtuple('Inv', 'pos, item_no, issue, qty, UM, price, amt')

new_vend_re = re.compile(r'\d+\s[A-Z].*')
text = "some\nmore (53 AB839-11 0002 31.00 EA 58.5300 1814.43) things \ntext\n"

line_items = []
for line in text.split('\n'):
    searched = new_vend_re.search(line)
    if searched:
        print(line)
        # get the matched part of the line and remove ( ) from start/end
        m = searched.group(0).strip("()")

        # now its as simple as splitting it into variables
        pos, item_no, issue, qty, UM, price, amt, *crap = m.split()

        # and use a namedtuple that works with that amount of data
        line_items.append(Inv(pos, item_no, issue, qty, UM, price, amt))

if crap:
    print(crap, "that was also captured but not used")

print(*line_items)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(line_items)
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
# line
more (53 AB839-11 0002 31.00 EA 58.5300 1814.43) things 

# crap catchall
['things'] that was also captured but not used

# named tuple
Inv(pos='53', item_no='AB839-11', issue='0002', qty='31.00', UM='EA', price='58.5300', amt='1814.43)')

# df
  pos   item_no issue    qty  UM    price       amt
0  53  AB839-11  0002  31.00  EA  58.5300  1814.43)
```

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my output. It doesnt necessarily give that same line as in the output that I've provided.. it's ONE of the values. But I shall try this code out and tweak it to my needs. It's basically a PDF with multiple pages in which I've to extract values that match that regex. I just gave that particular one as an example.

Comment: @f0rty .. thats why I told you to [edit] your question and to  "_Remove all the pdf handling stuff - it is irrelevant, we do not have your pdf and can not exectute your code on your file to get the text your regex operate on.  **Hardcode / add example text you extract from pdf** and want to apply your regexes to._"  - we on SO can only work with what you provide - you provided only one example for your data. But glad it helped.

Comment: Thank you, I have made some minor tweaks and I have finally got it to work. Appreciate your time and effort!